# How to generate the git merge --log message if using --no-commit, merge fails or is aborted?

Tags: git, merge

I am performing a `git merge` of two branches and wanted to include the `--log` switch, but forgot. I aborted the commit message editor to try again.

Now I'm in a situation where MERGE_HEAD exist, so I can't rerun merge and I'm instructed to "Please, commit your changes before you can merge."

When committing to complete the merge, I can't find an option to create the same message I would have gotten from the `merge --log` switch.

Q: Is the solution to delete `.git/MERGE_HEAD` then merge again, or is there some combination of `git commit` and `git fmt-merge-msg` that would generate a --log-like message?

I would think this might have been a common issue, but I have been unable to find a solution for this via git-smc, Google, or SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, if you started a merge and decide you don't want it after all, just use `git merge --abort`.  (Then you can restart it with different options.)

If you have actually done some work, though, you can just gather up the commit subjects messages (just as you suggested, using `git fmt-merge-msg`, for instance, or just using `git log --format='  %s' -n <num> branch`) and put them into the final merge that you make when you `git commit` the merge.

I have never used `git fmt-merge-msg --log` before but it appears to want, on standard input (or from a file), a series of lines of the form `git fetch` normally leaves in `FETCH_HEAD`:

- a raw SHA-1
- two literal tabs
- the name of the branch

hence (while on branch `example` in my test):

```
$ echo $(git rev-parse master)$'\t\t'"'master'" | git fmt-merge-msg --log
Merge 'master' into example

* master:
  [four commits listed here, in my case]
```

Once you have some base commit text like this, you can use commit's `-F <file>` option to read it from a file, or `-F -` to read it from standard input.

(Note: `git merge --log master` produced a slightly different message, namely:

```
Merge branch 'master' into example

* master:
  [same four commits listed]
```

If I change the `echo` command to say `branch 'master'`, the *first* line matches, but then the line prefixed with an asterisk says `branch 'master'`.)